# Colon in Erlang Cowboy

Tags: url, erlang, router, cowboy

I am using [leptus](https://github.com/sinasamavati/leptus), which is based on [Cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy), as a RESTful server. I have a problem with router.

In my code:

```
post("/restconf/operations/nm-restful:create-mp", Req, State) ->
    {200, {json, <<>>, State}.
```

In Cowboy, when there is a colon, it will do binding. But what if there is actually a colon in the URL path? I don't want it be bound. There's no information on this issue in the official website tutorial.

Comment: I looked at the source of `cowboy_router` and I don't think this is possible. I can't see any way to "escape" a colon in the source. If that's true, your best bet would be to match all such routes using `/restconf/operations/:anything` and then do a `case` on the value of the parameter `anything` inside the function.

Comment: @Dogbert your suggestion is a good workaround, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the source of `cowboy_router` (which leptus uses) and I don't think this is possible. I can't see any way to "escape" a colon in the source. If that's true, your best bet would be to match all such routes using `/restconf/operations/:anything` and then do a case on the value of the parameter anything inside the function. Here's an example:

```
post("/restconf/operations/:thing", Req, State) ->
  case leptus_req:param(Req, thing) of
    <<"nm-restful:create-mp">> ->
      {200, {json, <<>>, State};
    _ ->
      {404, {json, <<>>, State}.
```